# Pandas Series difference between accessing values using string and nested list

Tags: python, pandas, series

Hi I'm still new to pandas method and I just to have a better understanding about the pd.Series

```
ser = pd.Series(data=[100,"200",300,"400",500],index=["tom","bob","nancy","dan","eric"])
```

I found out when ever I want to extract a value using the index of it for example

```
ser["nancy"]
```

the output will be

```
300
```

but if i use nested list

```
ser[["nancy"]]
```

I will get

```
nancy    300
```

I know it's maybe a simple thing but I just want to know the reason behind that to have a better understanding 
and if there is any resource you would recommend I would highly appreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use:

```
ser["nancy"]
>> 300
```

it returns an integer

```
type(ser['nancy']
>> int
```

But when you use

```
ser[['nancy']]
>> nancy    300
dtype: object
```

It actually returns a series:

```
type(ser[['nancy']])
>> pandas.core.series.Series
```

So when you use a list, it always returns a series and not just the corresponding value as when you use just a string:

```
ser[["nancy", "dan"]]
>> nancy      300
dan    400
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `ser["nancy"]` you signal pandas you want a single value, so it will return the value at the `"nancy"` index key. When you do `ser[["nancy"]]` you signal pandas you may want multiple values, so it returns a data structure (in this case a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.html)) that contains those (possible) multiple values. This is better illustrated in the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(data=[100, "200", 300, "400", 500], index=["tom", "bob", "nancy", "dan", "eric"])

result = ser["nancy"]
print(result, type(result))

result = ser[["nancy", "dan"]]
print(result, type(result))
```

**Output**

```
300 <class 'int'>
nancy    300
dan      400
dtype: object <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

As you can see from the output, `ser["nancy"]` return the value of `ser` at `"nancy"`, in this case 300, you can further verify that is a single value by it's type (int). For the second case the type of result is a Series.